# CaptionPanel and TabPanel in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there any reason why a CaptionPanel does not work within a TabPanel in Google Apps Script?  Here is a minimal example that shows the problem I am facing:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var outputPanel = app.createTabPanel();
  var panel1 = app.createCaptionPanel("One").add(app.createLabel("Hello One"));
  outputPanel.add(panel1, "One");
  var panel2 = app.createCaptionPanel("Two").add(app.createLabel("Hello Two"));
  outputPanel.add(panel2, "Two");
  app.add(outputPanel);
  return app;
}
```

This script does create two panels, but they do not show correctly and none of the two tabs can be selected.

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine for me. i.e. I can select the tabs and the caption panels show.

Well, I'd add a line to have a default selected tab (but that's not required), e.g.

```
outputPanel.selectTab(0);
```